Flickity.js clicks the link when dragging
So I've created a slider using Flickity, and it works fine, but my slides are links out of necessity. The problem arises when the draggable option is enabled. When I click and drag, instead of just dragging, it also triggers the link. Is there a way to handle this behavior with a simple option prop or something, without resorting to complex workarounds to prevent it?
